How to install CH340 driver in VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04?
I have downloaded the Zip file from producer's website and extracted it in Ubuntu directory, when I run "make", it was prompted:
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-41-generic/build  M=/home/mq/8051/Tools/CH341SER_LINUX/driver  
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0

make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic'
My question is: Is x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 and gcc-12 the same one or they are different? If I want to "make" run, what adjustments should I take?

That's only a warning - it shouldn't (by itself) prevent the compilation from succeeding - you can likely suppress it with make CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 if you wish. Did it produce a ch341.ko file?

Yes, it produced a ch341.ko file, but I couldn't find ttyUSB0 in /dev, maybe I havn't added user into the coordinated group?

Did you actually install the module? Can you verify its presence it with lsmod and/or modinfo?

First, I run "sudo make load", it was prompted: "insmod ch341.ko"
then, lsmod | grep ch34, it was prompted: "ch341                  28672  0"
sudo dmesg, it was prompted:
[  562.145312] ch341: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  562.145343] ch341: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  562.176331] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb_ch341
[  562.176352] ch341: USB serial driver for ch340, ch341, etc.
[  562.176355] ch341: V1.7 On 2023.07
and, there was no ttyUSB0 or other sign related to ch341 under "/dev"
